# How to display related posts based on tags in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a music site which uses a lot of tags and categories per post. For example, on an artist's page the related posts display that artist's releases based on tags. I have tried adding the tag using Wordpress' `post_type` to the `$args = array(`:

```
'post_type' => 'releases'
```

... but it hasn't worked.

Here is the complete code:

```php
<div class="relatedposts">
    <h3>Releases by Artist</h3>
    <?php
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
         
        if ($tags) {
        $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
        $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'releases',
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
        );
         
        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
             
        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();
        ?>

    <div class="relatedthumb">
        <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br />
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <? }
        }
        $post = $orig_post;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
</div>
```

I've followed a lot of other StackOverflow posts and can't seem to get the right result.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183494/related-posts-display-randomly-by-tag

Answer (score 1):

You can try this process getting posts that are related by Tag:

```
<?php
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page' => 3, 
   'post__not_in'   => array( get_the_ID() ), 
   'orderby' => 'count',
);

$cats = wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID(), 'tag' ); 
$cats_ids = array();  
foreach( $cats as $wpex_related_cat ) {
   $cats_ids[] = $wpex_related_cat->term_id; 
}
if ( ! empty( $cats_ids ) ) {
   $args['tag__in'] = $cats_ids;
}
$wpex_query = new wp_query( $args );
foreach( $wpex_query->posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><li><?php the_title(); ?></li></a>
    enter code here
<?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Fantastic, simple, and reliable snippet... thank you.

Comment: Similar results: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/183498/152624

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="row related">
    <div class="row related-articles">
        <h2 class="related-title">Related Content</h2>
        <div class="relatedposts">
            <?php
        $orig_post = $post;
        global $post;
        $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

        if ($tags) {
            $tag_ids = array();
        foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
            $args=array(
                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=>3, // Number of related posts to display.
                'caller_get_posts'=>1
            );

        $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

        while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();
        ?>
            <div class="large-4 medium-4 small-12 columns img-wrap"> <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>">
                <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') ); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $url ?>" />
                <div class="story-title-sub">
                    <h2>
                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php }
        }
        $post = $orig_post;
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I edited the above to the code i used on my site, it looks like the same script and it works on my site. Looks like the only real diffrence is you are calling the post type. Take a look and maybe you can find the answer in the above

Comment: Yeah that's the same code I was using. It calls all the relating tags. I've tried many variations in the $args = array(  section. Hmm. Puzzling.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for getting posts that are related by Tag

```
<?php // related posts based on first tag of current post
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {

    echo '<h3>Related Posts</h3>';

    $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
    $args = array(
            'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'showposts' => 7, // how many posts?
            'caller_get_posts' => 1
            );

    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()) { ?>

        <ul>

        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```